# remove noise from image to make it ready for tesseract ocr using python and open cv

Tags: python, image, opencv, captcha

I want to make the given image tesseract ready and remove noise from the given image. The background line removed and characters made horizontal is very useful. i want to extract characters from the image.

[image]

Comment: do some research first and post your code